# What date format is this - xx:xx.x?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, date, datetime

I have a task to parse CSV file and encountered this date format -xx:xx.x

Example: 25:47.1

And how can I parse it to MySQL datetime?

Comment: Simple logic should tell you `25:47.1` *must* be dd.yy.mm **if it is a date**

Comment: Looks like twenty-five minutes and forty-seven-point-one seconds to me.

Comment: Any context in the record to figure this one out? I agree that it looks more like a time interval than it does a date or a datetime or a time. For all we know that could be a two digit number of years since some undefined epoch, a colon, and then the julien days and hours in decimal format. Like an epoch of 1990: (2:24am, February 16th, 2015) I'm putting my bet on time interval though as Jeeped says.

Comment: Is there an actual start date/time somewhere in the file such as at the beginning and the rest are offsets?  Think of how times are kept for races where in a marathon for instance someone might have a time of 2 hrs 37 minutes etcs and then each person after that has some kind of offset indicataing how much additional time after the winner they took.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue in how excel is translating the date. A date-time of
`2014-09-26 07:03:07.473` in my CSV will look like the following in excel `03:07.5`

In researching this, excel makes this a time and rounding the ms by default
but if you click on the cell, it will present the full format.

I hope this helps. I would check the CSV to see what it shows if in doubt. If this is off base, please let me know.